# Snowflake query history weird results

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to look at the queries on certain tables and I'm getting weird results. I know for sure, there are atleast 5 queries on a certain table, but below queries are getting me different results. Anyone Snowflake users experienced similar issues.

```
SELECT QUERY_ID,QUERY_TEXT
from table(information_schema.query_history(       
end_time_range_start=>to_timestamp_ltz ('2022-03-29 11:00:00.000000'),     
end_time_range_end=>to_timestamp_ltz ('2022-03-29 14:00:00.000000')))    
where UPPER(query_text) like '%TABLE_NAME%'
```

-- This returns one record as result, Really weird behavior is when I increased the time range filter, I'm getting zero records (for below query). Does Snowflake stop execution if it finds data is so large

```
SELECT QUERY_ID,QUERY_TEXT
from table(information_schema.query_history(       
end_time_range_start=>to_timestamp_ltz ('2022-03-27 11:00:00.000000'),     
end_time_range_end=>to_timestamp_ltz ('2022-03-29 15:00:00.000000')))    
where UPPER(query_text) like '%TABLE_NAME%'
```

Currently I'm trying to run a script which calls above sql iteratively for 1 hour interval and loads to a different table which  kind of gets me most of the data but feels like I still miss a lot of query history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is most likely happening is you are hitting the 10K rows limit earlier with the time range starting earlier, thus your WHERE clause is filter less results.

Which is to say the "tables" do not really behave as they "should" mostly because they are not tables.

Also without the `RESULT_LIMIT =>10000` [argument](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html#arguments) set, you will only be getting the default limit with is 100

try:

```
SELECT QUERY_ID, QUERY_TEXT
from table(information_schema.query_history(       
    end_time_range_start=>to_timestamp_ltz ('2022-03-27 11:00:00.000000'),     
    end_time_range_end=>to_timestamp_ltz ('2022-03-29 15:00:00.000000'),
    RESULT_LIMIT =>10000
))    
where query_text ilike '%TABLE_NAME%'
```

Comment: Its the same table table, I used upper case in both queries.. Its just I put a sample value there not to expose my original table name in the forum. The point is I used exactly same query just changing the time range filter and got less records for bigger interval which is weird. (Edited the question)

Comment: add the more likely answer as a new answer/prefix.

Comment: Thanks Man, adding result limit seems to get better results.. So without Result Limit, SF only takes 100 records from query history and then do your filter?

Comment: That what the docs say. But you query profile would show.